# Microservice notification better with Firebase or celery?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, architecture, notifications, microservices

I have a microservice project. I am using DRF. Now I need to add notification system to this project. Since we have multiple service notification can come from any service. We also have web version and mobile version in frontend.
Which will be better option for notification service? Notification with firebase or Notification with celery?

Comment: celery is a task scheduler, whereas firebase cloud-messaging is a messaging service. You would use both, the former for handling millions of messages at the same time and the latter to actually (push) messages to your frontend/mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Firebase Cloud Messaging and Celery are solving very different problems, so it's really not an either/or choice.
Firebase Cloud Messaging is a service for sending push notifications to mobile apps. It handles all the complexities of reliably delivering messages to devices, even when they are offline.
Celery is a task queue for executing background jobs on your servers. It has nothing to do with push notifications or messaging clients directly.
So:

Use Firebase Cloud Messaging (or a similar service) to send push notifications to your mobile apps.
Use Celery (or a similar service) to orchestrate the background work of determining when push notifications need to be sent, and calling FCM to send them.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have mobile version, use Firebase Cloud Messagin and firestore with listening realtime updates. I will speed up your development with possibility to add new firebase features later.